# Emacs command to kill other buffer and window

Tags: emacs, window, buffer

Emacs has the function `kill-buffer-and-window` mapped to `C-x 4 0`. Naturally, I expected `C-x 4 1` to select the other window, kill the buffer and delete the window. I find myself using `C-x o` followed by `C-x 4 0` a lot, which is very tedious. The `q` command for closing **Help** windows still leaves the buffer open.

Is there a function that has the expected behaviour of `kill-other-buffer-and-window` ?

Comment: try binding a key to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3417473/8544157)

Comment: I found what I was looking for on [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KillingBuffers#toc5) `close-and-kill-next-pane`. Thank you @manandearth.